# Python. Как разбить число

Tags: python

У меня есть число **20**, как его разбить на 1,2,3,4,5,6..20.

Comment: что значит разбить? вам что цикл просто нужен?

Comment: Входные данные 20
Выходные 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9.. 20
Смотрите вот число 20. И мне нужно, чтобы мне на экран вывелись все числа начиная с 1 до 20.

Comment: `print(*list(range(1,21)))` ?

Comment: Знаю вопросы был очень глупым, но все равно спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Используй конструкцию `for in`

Пример:

```
for number in range(10):
      //Здесь будет вызываться код 10 раз и 
     //каждый раз (с каждой итерацией) number будет на 1 больше,
    //начиная с нуля
```

Этим можно воспользоваться и например выводить это число ). Как раз то что тебе и нужно.

Ну выводить можно с помощью `print`

Comment: Сразу говорю в Python не варюсь :/

Answer (score 1):

```
j = int(input("Введите число: ")) # Выводит сообщение "Введите число: " и ждет ввода

# Для range 1 аргумент - начальное число, второй - кол-во повторов
for i in range(1, j + 1): # j + 1 чтобы конечным числом было именно введенное число
    print (i) # Вывод на экран
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь